# Remove button from page if viewed through Customizer

Tags: jquery, theme-customizer

Is it possible to remove a specific button from the page only if it is viewed from the Customizer? I did try a check for `wp-customizer` in body, but this only checks the body of the iframe and not the main window.

So, any idea how to do this with jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

You did not wrote if you want to check it using PHP or JavaScript but if using PHP you can add to your theme a below function it will return true if the page is previewed using Customizer

```
function is_customizer_preview() {
  if( isset( $_GET['customize_theme'] ) ) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Then somewhere in the theme template files you can use it like that if you want to have an additional class in the body

```
<body class="some-classes <?php if(is_customizer_preview()): ?>my-customizer-class<?php endif; ?>">
```

Comment: ? That function already exists: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_customize_preview/

Comment: I did not know about this function, sorry.

Comment: Sorry, did not specify I want to check this with Javascript/jQuery!